# Correct input for TimeDistributed Convolution2D Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a sequence of 327 frames of dimension 480 rows and 640 colums, greyscale.

print (X_train.shape) 
gives:(327, 480, 640, 1)

I have the following model:

```
N = 2 #number of frames to distribute
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, activation='relu'), input_shape = (N, 480,640,1)))
...
```

print (model.output_shape) 
gives:(None, 2, 480, 640, 32)

I need one more dimension to pass to this input to the convolution.
In fact I have the following error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (327, 480, 640, 1)

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Edit: Fundamentally what I need is to transform the input (327, 480, 640, 1) into (x, 2, 480, 640, 1) (x=327/2 ?)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say you got a sequence of 327 frames. But your timestep for the model is 2.

Comment: Yes, I want to take frames 2 by 2. 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 ... Maybe something is not correct?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're trying to do. May be rewrite your problem including an example scenario or something.

Comment: I added an edit. I just have some difficult to re-arrange my data to work.

Comment: If you want to do a reshape, the total elements need to match. 327/2 doesn't result in an integer so it is not possible for you to reshape this tensor in a way you'd have 2 time steps. What you can do is get the first 326 and reshape that to [163, 2, 480, 640, 1].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a 2D convolution on 3D data (2x480x640). Use the [Convolution3D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D).